# How do I convert string of int slice to int slice?

Tags: string, go, slice

Example input: (type: `string`)

```
"[156, 100, 713]"
```

Example conversion: (type: slice of `int`)

```
[156, 100, 713]
```

Comment: What have tried already? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to mhutter's answer, also note that your input `string` looks like a JSON array (maybe it is from a JSON text?).

If you treat it like that, you may unmarshal its content into an `[]int` slice. This won't be faster that directly parsing the numbers from it (as the [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package uses reflection), but it is certainly simpler:

```
s := "[156, 100, 713]"

var is []int
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &is); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(is)
fmt.Printf("%#v", is)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/YFV3CH8vVn)):

```
[156 100 713]
[]int{156, 100, 713}
```

Answer (score 8):

Given a string

```
in := "[156, 100, 713]"
```

First, let's get rid of the square brackets:

```
trimmed := strings.Trim(in, "[]")
//=> "156, 100, 713"
```

Next, split the string into a slice of strings:

```
strings := strings.Split(trimmed, ", ")
//=> []string{"156", "100", "713"}
```

Now we can convert the strings to ints

```
ints := make([]int, len(strings))

for i, s := range strings {
    ints[i], _ = strconv.Atoi(s)
}

fmt.Printf("%#v\n", ints)
//=> []int{156, 100, 713}
```

For more Information see the go docs: https://devdocs.io/go/strings/index